# Using aligned and align without amsmath

Tags: amsmath, align

I am currently working on a proceedings paper, and have realised after finishing it that only specific packages are permitted - one of which is not `amsmath`. As a result, many of the nice equations that I have written can now no longer be built. To save me switching back to `\begin{cases} \end{cases}` and giving up, I thought I would try asking on here to see if anyone could provide me with a solution?

I cannot define add any new commands before `\begin{document}`, so everything must be done after that point. I thought about trying to grab the relevant components from the style file, but to be perfectly honest I am not a TeX-wizard and have no idea whether this would even work.Could anyone provide me with a work-around, so that I can still use align and aligned, but by doing so after `\begin{document}`?

If it helps, the packages I am permitted to use are:

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}       
\usepackage{helvet}         
\usepackage{courier}        
\usepackage{type1cm}        
\usepackage{graphicx}        
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}    
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{amsfonts}   
\usepackage{amsbsy}   
\usepackage{amscd}   
\usepackage{amstext}   
\usepackage{dsfont}   
\usepackage[english]{babel}   
\usepackage{color}   
\usepackage{graphics}   
\usepackage{epsfig}   
\usepackage{subfigure}   
\usepackage{wrapfig}   
\usepackage{psfrag}   
\usepackage{color}   
\usepackage{url}   
\usepackage{verbatim}   
\usepackage{algorithm}   
\usepackage{algorithmic}
```

Edit: An MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{svmult}   
\usepackage{mathptmx}       
\usepackage{helvet}         
\usepackage{courier}        
\usepackage{type1cm}        

\usepackage{graphicx}        

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{InitSystemNL}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{R} \colon= -\Delta u &= f  \quad & &\text{in} \,\, \Omega \\ u &= 0 \quad & &\text{on} \,\, \partial\Omega, \end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Two comments: (1) It's possible to define commands/enviroments *after* `\begin{document}`, if needed. (2) Mimicking `align`-like styles are possible, but could depend on your application. Most notably would be using a regular `array` environment. However, it's difficult to address this fully without seeing some form of [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: Hi Werner, thanks for the quick reply. I have edited my original response to include the MWE. Hope this helps - please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: Really!!! A math publication that prohibits `amsmath`?  That to me seems kind of ridiculous.  I don't quite understand why there should be such restrictions. I know if I had gotten this far and something and was rejected for a package reason I would just copy the entire package and make it part of my content!! :-)  I know that this is not a very helpful comment, but [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: So you're open to a solution that requires you to redo all your `align`-like structures into something like `array`?

Comment: If it was possible to edit the original equation to fit with array in such a way that the output when compared to the original with amsmath was similar, then yes, I would be prepared to edit the document. I imitially suggested trying to use \aligned and \align after \begin{document} though as I have used them in about 17 places, so a fair bit of editing will be needed if I choose this route.

Comment: This is simply crazy: they allow `epsfig` but don't allow `amsmath` and `graphicx`! :(

Comment: may one ask what the publication is, and who is the publisher?  it's rather peculiar to allow `amscd` and not `amsmath`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid needing to edit the existing doc you can defined a poor man's aligned as follows (but first try to get the rules changed)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{mathptmx}       
\usepackage{helvet}         
\usepackage{courier}        
\usepackage{type1cm}        

\usepackage{graphicx}        

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}


\begin{document}
\def\aligned{\vcenter\bgroup\let\\\cr
\halign\bgroup&\hfil${}##{}$&${}##{}$\hfil\cr}
\def\endaligned{\crcr\egroup\egroup}

\begin{equation}
\label{InitSystemNL}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{R} \colon= -\Delta u &= f  \quad & &\text{in} \,\, \Omega \\ u &= 0 \quad & &\text{on} \,\, \partial\Omega, 
\end{aligned} 
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, its saved me a lot of work. I originally used Werner's suggestion, however this has dealt with most of the issues for me.

Comment: Just to follow up, I also need a workaround for subequations, if you have one or know how? I have posted a separate topic from this one to save confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example showing the output generated *with* and *without* [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

[image]

```
\documentclass{svmult}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}

\noindent With \verb|amsmath|:
\begin{equation}
  \left\{\begin{aligned}
    \mathcal{R} \colon= -\Delta u &= f  \quad & &\text{in} \,\, \Omega \\ 
    u &= 0 \quad & &\text{on} \,\, \partial\Omega,
  \end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}

\noindent Without \verb|amsmath|:
\begin{equation}
  \left\{\begin{array}{r@{}l@{\qquad}l}
    \mathcal{R}\colon=-\Delta u & {}=f & \textrm{in}\ \Omega \\[\jot]
    u & {}=0 & \textrm{on}\ \partial\Omega,
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The most important part to address is the choice of your column specification in order to adequately address the alignment matching with that of `align` or `aligned`. The use of `\jot` is to provide a similar line-spacing to array between rows.

Comment: How come the majuscule greek are in italic?

Comment: @morbusg: That's the way `svmult` defines it. It uses a different font.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This certainly works - I have no idea how you came up with such a solution though! I have used the method proposed above for now, as it seems the easiest option to use, and keeps the formatting the same. Thanks, Chris