# Using subequations without amsmath

Tags: amsmath, subequations

Following on from [my previous question regarding the use of `align` and `aligned` without 'amsmath'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85984/6865), I am currently working on a proceedings paper, and have realised after finishing it that only specific packages are permitted - one of which is not `amsmath`. As a result, many of the nice equations that I have written can now no longer be built. To save me switching back to `\begin{cases} \end{cases}` and giving up, I thought I would try asking on here to see if anyone could provide me with a solution? My issue is now with subequations, I will provide a working example below.

I cannot define any new commands before `\begin{document}`, so everything must be done after that point (these are as per the MWE). I thought about trying to grab the relevant components from the style file, but to be perfectly honest I am not a TeX-wizard and have no idea whether this would even work.Could anyone provide me with a work-around, so that I can still use subequations, but by doing so after `\begin{document}`?

An MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{svmult}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{type1cm}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\label{DD}
\begin{align}
&\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
-\Delta e_{i}^1 +  c_1 &= f_i  \quad & &\text{in} \,\, \Omega_i \\ e_{i}^1 &= 0 \quad & &\text{on} \,\, \partial\Omega_i \end{aligned}
\label{DD1}
\end{cases}
\\
&\begin{cases}
\label{DD2}
\begin{aligned}
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N  \mathbf{n}_i \cdot r^1 &= - \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbf{n}_i \cdot r^2 \,\, & &\textrm{on} \,\, \Gamma \end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\\
&\begin{cases}
\label{DD3}
begin{aligned}
-\Delta e_{i}^2 + c_2 &= 0  \quad & &\text{in} \,\, \Omega_i \\
e_{i}^2 &= 0 \quad & &\text{on} \,\, \partial\Omega_i.  \end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated version adjusting spacing and labels, showing amsmath on the right and this code on the left

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{mathptmx}       
\usepackage{helvet}         
\usepackage{courier}        
\usepackage{type1cm}        

\usepackage{graphicx}        

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}


\begin{document}

\ifx\aligned\undefined

\makeatletter
\def\aligned{{\ifnum0=`}\fi\vcenter\bgroup\let\\\cr
\halign\bgroup&\hfil$\displaystyle{}##{}$&$\displaystyle{}##{}$\hfil\cr}
\def\endaligned{\crcr\egroup\egroup\ifnum0=`{\fi}}

\def\align{\par
\bigskip
{\ifnum0=`}\fi
\let\\\cr
\halign to \textwidth\bgroup
\refstepcounter{equation}%
\global\let\@alignlab\@currentlabel
\vrule \@height \dimexpr\ht\strutbox+3pt\relax
       \@depth  \dimexpr\dp\strutbox+1pt\relax
       \@width \z@
\hbox to \textwidth{\hfill(\theequation)}\kern-\textwidth
\tabskip\fill
\hfil$\displaystyle{}##{}$&%
\let\@currentlabel\@alignlab$\displaystyle{}##{}$\hfil&%
\let\@currentlabel\@alignlab\hfil$\displaystyle{}##{}$&%
\let\@currentlabel\@alignlab$\displaystyle{}##{}$\hfil\cr}
\def\endalign{\crcr\egroup\ifnum0=`{\fi}\par\bigskip}

\newcounter{parentequation}
\newenvironment{subequations}{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \edef\theparentequation{\theequation}%
  \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}


\def\cases{{\ifnum0=`}\fi\left\{\array{lll}}
\def\endcases{\endarray\right.\ifnum0=`{\fi}}

\makeatother
\fi



\begin{subequations}
\label{DD}
\begin{align}
&\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
-\Delta e_{i}^1 +  c_1 &= f_i  \quad & &\text{in} \,\, \Omega_i \\ e_{i}^1 &= 0 \quad & &\text{on} \,\, \partial\Omega_i \end{aligned}
\label{DD1}
\end{cases}
\\
&\begin{cases}
\label{DD2}
\begin{aligned}
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N  \mathbf{n}_i \cdot r^1 &= - \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbf{n}_i \cdot r^2 \,\, & &\textrm{on} \,\, \Gamma \end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\\
&\begin{cases}
\label{DD3}
\begin{aligned}
-\Delta e_{i}^2 + c_2 &= 0  \quad & &\text{in} \,\, \Omega_i \\
e_{i}^2 &= 0 \quad & &\text{on} \,\, \partial\Omega_i.  \end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}



\begin{equation}
\label{InitSystemNL}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{R} \colon= -\Delta u &= f  \quad & &\text{in} \,\, \Omega \\ u &= 0 \quad & &\text{on} \,\, \partial\Omega, 
\end{aligned} 
\right.
\end{equation}


[\ref{DD}][\ref{DD3}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its almost fine in my document, however I find that it 'bunches' up to the text both at the top and bottom when I view the output. Also, I would like the equations to center if possible as per the subequations environment, but cannot use \centering as it has no effect. Do you have any possible workarounds?

Comment: amsmath does a complicated double scan over each equation measuring stuff on the first pass and laying it out on the second, there are some compromises to make something that makes sense to define inline. actually you probably want \displaystyle in all the $...$ sections in the definitions so that the cells use display style,  you could stick \bigskip (or \addvspace{some space you like} at the start of \align and end of \endalign, centering is harder, might look but not at this time:-)

Comment: No problem - thanks anyway for the help. If you make any progress, i'd certainly be happy to hear of it. It is strange that the proceedings does not have amsmath as a core package, but this is the last issue. The document now builds fine, just the centering and linespace issues, but i'll try what you mentioned in the first instance.

Comment: To followup on my previous post (again, dont worry until you have sufficient time) - good point is that \bigskip or equivalent works a treat with the spacing.

Unfortunately, I have found another bad point, in that the labelling I use for \subequations is now creating problems in the file. If I refer to DD2 for example in the above working example, I am given the same number as if I refer to either DD1, DD3 or DD - which is certainly very strange?!?

Comment: code updated a bit

Comment: Thanks David - thats superb. I found I needed to mess a little with the spacing between subequations by adding artificial \vspace as I found that the cases brackets would bunch a little too close together, however i'm sure this could have been incorporated to what you wrote easily. Either way, that was definetly what I was looking for.